# getopt не распознаёт параметр

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код, в котором заданы два параметра - либо `-h`, либо `--help`:

```
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, 'ht:a:', ['target=', 'auth='])
except getopt.GetoptError as err:
    print(err)
    showUsage()
    sys.exit(2)
for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ('-h', '--help'):
        showUsage()
        sys.exit(2)
    elif ...
```

Но почему-то `-h` распознаётся, а `--help` - нет. Почему?

Comment: Можно узнать почему getopt а на argparse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что getopt не знает, о том, что есть `--help` - ему нужно явно сообщить

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, 'ht:a:', ['help', 'target=', 'auth='])
```